# Macro expansion within a macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, variadic-macros

I'm trying to create LOGDEBUG macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_TEST 1
#else
#define DEBUG_TEST 0
#endif

#define LOGDEBUG(...) do { if (DEBUG_TEST) syslog(LOG_MAKEPRI(LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_DEBUG),  __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

...

size_t haystack_len = fminl(max_haystack_len, strlen(haystack_start));
LOGDEBUG(("haystack_len %ld\n", haystack_len));
```

I am not using # or ## parameters to stringify the arguments, and yet g++ apparently tries to stringify them:

```
numexpr/interpreter.cpp:534:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Note that `haystack_len` is `size_t` and I do not convert it to `char*` in the macro, yet compiler sees it as such. Does g++ implicitly tries to convert macro arguments to strings?

How to fix that? I mean, I'm using gnu LOG_MAKEPRI macro for syslogging, is it this macro that may be causing trouble? Also, is there some way to see the macro-expanded code?

Comment: I think you have 2 extra parenthesis in LOGDEBUG call. (you pass only 1 argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix that?

`LOGDEBUG(("haystack_len %ld\n", haystack_len));` call the macro with one unique argument.
So it will produce:

```
do { if (DEBUG_TEST) syslog(LOG_MAKEPRI(LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_DEBUG), ("haystack_len %ld\n", haystack_len)); } while (0);
```

And `("haystack_len %ld\n", haystack_len)` use comma operator and result in `haystack_len`

So you have to call it that way: `LOGDEBUG("haystack_len %ld\n", haystack_len);`

> Also, is there some way to see the macro-expanded code?

`gcc -E` may help.